# How do I get axe-core-react to check re-renders of my app?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, axe

I have an [Ionic React app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react) that I am trying to test using [axe-core-npm](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core-npm/tree/develop/packages/react)

Here's my basic app setup:

```
const startAccessibilityTestingIfDebug = () => {
  if (showDebugInfo) {
    import('@axe-core/react').then((axe) => {
      axe.default(React, ReactDOM, 1000, config);
      startIonic();
    });
  } else {
    startIonic();
  }
};

const startIonic = () => {
  setupIonicReact();
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
};
```

When I serve my app via `npm run serve` (Ionic is using CRA v5), then my app loads at `localhost:8100` and I can see the `axe` errors in the browser's console-- but only for the initial page load.

Even if I navigate to different pages of my app (Ionic uses `react-router` v5), I don't see any new `axe` information.  If I reload the page, I do see the new errors.

So, it seems like `axe` is only printing information for the initial page load, but it should be printing info for every component load.  What am I doing wrong?

I found [this tutorial on using axe to test accessibility](https://dev.to/stories_of_ren/taking-the-axe-to-inaccessibility-4dkj), and the comments suggest other people are having the same problem. There is no solution identified in those comments.

Comment: Are you seeing any logs after the initial page load but before navigating? For example, if you have things on the first page that trigger new elements to load or hide, does axe trigger logs for those events?

Comment: @StevenLambert In the browser console, I get logs for the very first page, but only once.  The "initial page load" actually includes several calls to React `<Suspend>`, but I only get one set of axe issues.

Comment: Just a heads up, we might have identified the problem. Are you by chance using react 17? We were notified of a problem with react 17 using @axe-core/react and have a pr opened that might fix it https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core-npm/pull/437

Comment: @StevenLambert Yes, I'm using react 17.  I'll try to check out the PR when I get a free moment.

Comment: Update on this. We released @axe-core/react 4.4.1 which should now properly support React 17. Might fix this particular issue.